# How are IP broadcasts handled at lower levels

Tags: ip, mac-address, arp

When I use a broadcast IP address, for example 198.255.255.255, what will happen when it gets passed down to the link-layer which will then look for the corresponding MAC address in your ARP table. Does your ARP table have an entry for 198.255.255.255;FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF, if not, how can the link-layer know it should use FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF as physical address to broadcast it into the subnet?

Thanks
-Vexea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does your ARP table have an entry for
> 198.255.255.255;FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF?

Yes, it does if that is your network broadcast address. It will also have an entry for the Limited Broadcast address `255.255.255.255` relating to `ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff`.

You can see this if you show your ARP table (`arp -a` for Windows).

Comment: when you look at my previous questions from months ago when I just started, you answered some of them, thank you for your help!